# Proving $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{\alpha +x_n}, x_0=\sqrt \alpha, \alpha>0$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

Picking up from where [this question left off](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333050/how-do-i-prove-the-sequence-x-n1-sqrt-alpha-x-n-x-0-sqrt-alpha-alph)...

I have my own take on this proof. I started by showing, by induction, that the sequence is monotonically increasing, and then, also by induction, I showed that the sequence is bounded above by $ x_n<1+\sqrt{a}$. (I can include this if need be) But I want to know if this sequence actually converges to $1+\sqrt{a}$. I know that this sequence is *bounded above* by this, but I don't know if it is the *lease upper bound*. Would anyone have any intuition as to prove that, or even where to begin?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Suppose $x_n$ converged to $x$. Then $x$ should satisfy $x = \sqrt{\alpha+x}$. Does your proposed limit satisfy this?

Comment: As per what Fimpellizieri said and showed, yes! Thank you!

Comment: Special case of [$\sqrt{c+\sqrt{c+\sqrt{c+\cdots}}}$, or the limit of the sequence $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{c+x_n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115501/sqrtc-sqrtc-sqrtc-cdots-or-the-limit-of-the-sequence-x-n1-sq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the sequence is bounded and monotonic, then it certainly converges. Now, since you have a relation between $x_{n+1}$ and $x_n$ (that is expressed via a continuous function), you can use a little trick to 'brute force' the value of the limit.

Let $L = \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$. Then $$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{\alpha +x_n}=\sqrt{\lim_{n\to\infty}(\alpha+x_n)}=\sqrt{\alpha+L}$$

so that $L^2=\alpha+L$, or $L^2-L-\alpha=0$. Then
$$L=\frac{1\pm \sqrt{1+4\alpha}}{2}$$

Of course, we know $L>0$, so we pick the positive sign.

Comment: So the *brute force* part is just reapplying the limit recursively into $x_n$? If so, wow, that makes things very easy!

Comment: Yes! We can do this because the recursion is given by a continuous expression (this justifies the third equality in $L = \dots = \sqrt{\alpha + L}$). Put another way, this kind of recursion makes progressively smaller changes to our $x_n$ iterates (it's converging!), and in the limit it makes no change at all.

Comment: Fascinating. Thank you! I will have to leave an exercise for myself why that is true. Thank you thank you.

Comment: Looking back at the original question, I see why I got confused with his/her proof, the solution never seemed to explicitly state your step/reasoning above, or *why*.