# If $a>0$ and $z_{1}>0$ define $z_{n+1}=\sqrt{a+z_{n}}$ show that it converges and find the limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I have attempted this problem and came up with the following method to solve it

One can show that the sequence $z_{n+1}=\sqrt{a+z_{n}}$ is monotone  I assumed it's increasing as a case study , therefore relying on the monotone convergence theorem

I tried to estimate a possible candidate for a bound, assuming $(z_{n})$ converges we get

$$\lim_{n}z_{n+1}=\lim_{n}\sqrt{a+z_{n}}\implies z=\sqrt{a+z}$$

therefore

$$z^2-z-a=0\implies z=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4a}}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+a}$$

If the sequence converges choose $z=\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{1/4+a}$ this would be the sequences supremum and $\frac{1}{2}\pm \sqrt{1/4+a}\leq 4+a$

therefore I made the claim that $z_{n}\leq a+4, \; \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, and I tried to prove it as follows

assume there exists $n_{0}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $z_{n_{0}}>a+4$ then

$$S=\{n\in\mathbb{N}:z_{n}>a+4\}\neq \emptyset$$

thus by the well ordering principle it attains a least element say $m$ but then

$$\begin{align}z_{m}&>a+4  \\ 
\sqrt{a+z_{m-1}}&>a+4 \\
a+z_{m-1}&>a^2+8a+16 \\ 
z_{m-1}>(a+4)+(a^{2}+6a+12)&>a+4   \end{align}$$

This would contradict the choose of $m$ and create an infinite descent therefore, $(z_{n})$ is a monotone and bounded sequence thus it's convergent and it's limit is the supremum suggested above

Comment: "*WLOG I assumed it's increasing*" $\;-\;$ You'll have to justify the "*WLOG*" claim since it's not obvious here.

Comment: @dxiv my bad I meant to write I considered the case where $(z_{n})$ is increasing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let $a&gt;0$ and $x_1 &gt; 0$ and $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{a + x_n}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that $\{x_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2246842/let-a0-and-x-1-0-and-x-n1-sqrta-x-n-for-n-in-mathbbn-s) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24z_%7Bn%2B1%7D%3D%5Csqrt%7Bz_n%2Ba%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aconverges%2C%20OR%20content%3Alimit&p=1). Note the search results include multiple other duplicates, with some of these closed as duplicates of other questions and/or have links to them, ...

Comment: (cont.) e.g., [Show that the following inductively defined sequence converges and find its limit.](/q/2280414), [Convergence and limit of a recursive sequence $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{p+x_n}$](/q/685165), [Monotone series increases and decreases depending on first term. What is the limit?](/q/3101894), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DIRECT PROOF OF CONVERGENCE

First note that all $z_n$ are positive.

Let $t=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4a}}{2}$, then $t>1$ and $t^2=a+t$.

Then $z_{n+1}^2-t^2=a+z_n-(a+t)=z_n-t$. Therefore

$$ |z_{n+1}-t|=\frac{|z_n-t|}{|z_{n+1}+t|}<\frac{|z_n-t|}{t}.$$

And therefore $\{z_n\}$ tends to $t$.

COMMENTS ON YOUR SOLUTION

You are correct in stating that the sequence is monotone but this does need proving. (The proof is similar to the one above, replacing $t$ by $z_n)$.

Your argument that $a+4$ is an upper bound is clever but is not strictly correct since the descent need not be infinite but could end with $z_1>a+4$. Since $z_1$ is arbitrary this could happen and in that case you would have to show that the sequence is monotonic decreasing.

I hope these comments are of use.