# $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{a+x_{n}}, x_1=\sqrt{a}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, proof-writing, solution-verification

I have to show that the sequence $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{a+x_{n}}, x_1=\sqrt{a}$ has limit etc. This is part b) of a,b,c on the hw question, to show that this sequence is increasing. On part a) I proved $x_n<1+\sqrt{a}$ but it seems very useless.  Is my way to show that $x_{n+1}>x_{n}$ Correct? Also $a>0$
$\text{By induction: } x_n<\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4a}}{2}
\\
\text{Base case: }x_1=\sqrt{a}<\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{a}=\frac{1+\sqrt{4a}}{2}<\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4a}}{2}\\
\text{Assume: }\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, x_n<\frac{1+\sqrt{4a}}{2} \\
4a+4x_n<4a+4(\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4a}}{2}) \Rightarrow 4(a+x_n)<1+2\sqrt{1+4a}+1+4a \Rightarrow (a+x_n)<\frac{(1+\sqrt{1+4a})^2}{4} \Rightarrow \\x_{n+1}=\sqrt{a+x_n}<\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4a}}{2}\\
\text{Thus this inequality is proved. Now notice that:}\\
x_n-\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4a}}{2}<0 \text{ from the above inequality, and }\\ x_n-\frac{1-\sqrt{1+4a}}{2}>0 \text{ is obvious since the 1 inside the sqrt will kill the 1 outside for all a>0.}
\\
\therefore 0>(x_n-\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4a}}{2})(x_n-\frac{1-\sqrt{1+4a}}{2})=x_{n}^{2}-x_n-a\Rightarrow x_n+a>x_n^2 \Rightarrow \sqrt{x_n+a}>x_n\Rightarrow x_{n+1}>x_n. \\
$

Comment: Sounds good to me. It seems duplicated: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333050/how-do-i-prove-the-sequence-x-n1-sqrt-alpha-x-n-with-x-0-sqrt-alpha

Comment: I saw that but they say that the inequality is "obvious" and don't prove it. My professor wouldnt like "obvious" as an argument lmao haha

Comment: @Goob For a shortcut: $\,x_{n+1}-x_n=\sqrt{a+x_{n}}-\sqrt{a+x_{n-1}}=\frac{x_n-x_{n-1}}{\sqrt{a+x_{n}}+\sqrt{a+x_{n-1}}}\,$, so the differences between consecutive terms have the same sign.

Comment: o thats cool ty

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I prove the sequence $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{\alpha +x_n}$, with $x_0=\sqrt \alpha$ converges? ( boundedness?)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333050/how-do-i-prove-the-sequence-x-n1-sqrt-alpha-x-n-with-x-0-sqrt-alpha)

Comment: no I saw it before I solved and it didnt help me